# .local/share/applications isn't detected by xdg-mime

Tags: arch-linux, .desktop, xdg-open

I'm trying to change the default program to open PDF files with `xdg-open` using the command `xdg-mime default pdf.desktop application/pdf`.

The file `pdf.desktop` is already in `~/.local/share/applications`.

### Summary of what I've tried

```
rik@arch ~ : xdg-mime query default application/pdf
firefox.desktop
rik@arch ~ : xdg-mime default pdf.desktop application/pdf
rik@arch ~ : xdg-mime query default application/pdf
firefox.desktop
rik@arch ~ : update-desktop-database ~/.local/share/applications
rik@arch ~ : xdg-mime query default application/pdf
firefox.desktop
rik@arch ~ : xdg-mime default pdf.desktop application/pdf
rik@arch ~ : xdg-mime query default application/pdf
firefox.desktop
```

I can change it with these steps if I put the `pdf.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`.

### Content of `pdf.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Zathura
Exec=zathura
```

I'm using Arch Linux (up-to-date).

What can I try to set `pdf.desktop` as default for `application/pdf` without moving any file to `/usr/share/applications`?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this issue by correctly setting the XDG variables:

```
export XDG_DATA_HOME="$HOME/.local/share"
export XDG_CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.config"
export XDG_CACHE_HOME="$HOME/.cache"
```